INNER JOIN en consulta a dos tablas buscando un valor en ambas tablas
Hola a todos espero me puedan ayudar con esto.. (soy novato asi que perdonen si soy un poco torpe y es una pregunta tonta)
necesito hacer una consulta a dos tablas permisos y extension_incapacidad y uso INNER JOIN donde en la tabla permisos y extension_incapacidad tienen en comun codigo_documentos y code_ext como traigo una variable pasada vía POST id que es la que tienen que consultar, hice esta estructura pero no me resulta...
$sql.="SELECT * permisos INNER JOIN extension_incapacidad ON codigo_documentos WHERE codigo_docuausentismos AND code_ext=$id";


Pues, hay varios errores durante la consulta.
Primero que nada estás iniciando la consulta sql con una concatenación .=, no se si esto sea intencional, pero no lo parece.
Segundo, el SELECT va acomapañado de un FROM, para indicar la selección y la tabla.
SELECT *
FROM permisos [...]

Tercero, tenenos el JOIN, en este caso es un INNER JOIN, pasaré de explicarlo dado que como lo estás usando creo que entiendes de que va.
Pero el error está en que el INNER JOIN debe indicar TABLA, y luego las variables por la cuales vamos a comparar la información
INNER JOIN [TABLA] ON [dato1] = [dato2]

Acá hace falta esa comparación, en tu código está incompleto
INNER JOIN extension_incapacidad ON codigo_documentos = [dato2]

Y por Cuarto y último, tenemos el WHERE con AND, condiciones.
WHERE codigo_docuausentismos 
AND code_ext=$id

Acá el error está en que no indicas las condiciones para el primer dato. Fijate que en el AND el code_ext esta siendo comparado con el $id.
WHERE codigo_docuausentismos = [dato2]
AND code_ext = $id

Tu consulta completa debería ser algo como:
SELECT p.* --Selecciona los datos a mostrar de la tabla permisos
FROM permisos p --tabla permisos p
INNER JOIN extension_incapacidad ec --Join a tabla ec
ON ec.variableID = p.variableID --datos a comprar de ec y p
WHERE codigo_docuausentismos = dato2 -- acá debe ser p.codigo.. o c.codigo..
AND p.code_ext=$id --mismo caso aca, p es de la tabla permisos


Hola mil gracias por responder.. con respecto a --Selecciona los datos a mostrar de la tabla permisos. ¿Debo allí escribir los campos y si son todos hay que especificar uno a uno??? no se puede un * para decir seleccione todos los campos de la tabla 1 y  todos los campos de la tabla 2..

Si te fijas, permisos tiene un alias, el cual es p. Al momento de hacer p.*, estamos indicando que nos traiga todas las columnas de la tabla permisos. Para seleccionar la otra tabla, tendrías que añadir la otra tabla a la selección igual, con el uso de ec.*. No puedes solo usar un * para ambas, porque sino el código no sabe de donde tiene que traer la información.

bueno lo hice algo asi pero nada aun:
SELECT p.* FROM permisos p INNER JOIN ec.* extension_incapacidad ec ON ec.code_ext = p.codigo_documentos WHERE p.codigo_documentos = '123' AND ec.code_ext='123'

En tu publicacion, agrega las tablas a unir, y los datos a obtener. Muestra un ejemplo del resultado, aunque sea manual.
